# Why is my code for a random answer getter not working?

Tags: python

Basically I made some code for a random test answer getter. My idea was it would give you random answers from an a b c d selection. When I run the code it seems to shut out of the program.

Here is the code:

```
import random
Question_total = int(input("How Many answers do you need?"))
x = random.choice('abcd')
print(x * Question_total)
```

When I input a number it just exits out. Here is the error(I input four):

```
dddd
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a loop. You're generating one random result, and then repeating that result string several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does exactly what it should. If you look closely, you will see that it printed `dddd`. The way that you have it written, it grabs *one* value from `'abcd'` and prints it `Question_total` times (`x * Question_total`). If instead you want to grab `Question_total` *different* values you need to call `random.choice('abcd')` that many times.

```
Question_total = int(input("How Many answers do you need?"))

# Choose from 'abcd' Question_total different times and create a list of choices
choices = [random.choice('abcd') for _ in range(Question_total)]
print ' '.join(choices)

# a b d a
```

Or if you want to write it out as a for loop

```
Question_total = int(input("How Many answers do you need?"))

choices = list()

# Go through the loop Question_total times
for x in range(Question_total):
    # Make a choice
    newchoice = random.choice('abcd')

    # Stick the choice in a list so we can remember it
    choices.append(newchoice)

    # Print the choice
    print newchoice
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but do you think you can tell me how I would change my current code inorder to get it to call choices multiple times? I tried to run that code and it gave me this error:             print(*choices)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.     so I don't know how to format it correctly in a comment but it says that the print statement is not valid syntax.

Comment: @jameslatimer Sorry I figured you were on python 3. It should work now. Also this code is *already* an adaptation of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing what it i s supposed to. You give it a number then you pick one random letter and multiply it by that number

In Python, string * number returns the string concatenated to itself number times

What you need to do is do

```
for _ in range(input number):
    Print one random letter
```